# If $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2011}=a+b\sqrt{2}$, for integers $a$ and $b$, then what is $\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^{2010}$ expressed using $a$ and $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Being $ a $ and $ b $ integers such that $\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2011} =a+b\sqrt{2}, \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{2010}$ equals:
>
> a) $a+2b+(a-b)\sqrt{2}$
>
> b) $a-2b+(a-b)\sqrt{2}$
>
> c) $a+2b+(b-a)\sqrt{2}$
>
> d) $2b-a+(b-a)\sqrt{2}$
>
> e) $a+2b-(a+b)\sqrt{2}$

Solution:

[image]

Not going with any of the alternatives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point is that $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2011}=a+b\sqrt{2}$ implies
$\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^{2011}=a-b\sqrt{2}$.
Therefore,
$$
\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^{2010}
=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^{2011}}{1-\sqrt2}
=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^{2011}(1+\sqrt2)}{(1-\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)}
=-(a-b\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)
= \cdots
$$

Comment: Finishing this answer, I got D

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $(1+\sqrt{2})^n=a_n+b_n \sqrt{2}$ then $(1-\sqrt{2})^n=a_n-b_n \sqrt{2}$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+\sqrt{2})^{2011}=a+b \sqrt{2} \\
(1-\sqrt{2})^{2010}=x+y \sqrt{2}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the second equation by $(1-\sqrt{2})$ & do a bit of algebra ... this gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
x-2y=a\\
x-y=b .\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be easy from here ?

> d)

Comment: What alternative?

Comment: Solve the equations for $x$ & $y$ in terms of $a$ & $b$ ... or hover over the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x= \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{2010}$

Then $$x(a+b\sqrt{2}) = (1-2)^{2010}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)=1+\sqrt{2}$$

So $$x= {1+\sqrt{2}\over a+b\sqrt{2}}  =  {(1+\sqrt{2})( a-b\sqrt{2})\over a^2-2b^2}$$

Now $\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{2011} = a-b\sqrt{2}$ so $$a^2-2b^2 = (1-\sqrt{2})^{2011} \cdot \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2011} =-1$$

So $$x=(1+\sqrt{2})( -a+b\sqrt{2}) =...$$

Comment: The OP got there already. The OP did not know how to continue from there to get the final result.